# What's the strongest Naruto transformation?

Tags: naruto, boruto

I thought the form Naruto used in the 4th shinobi war, with the truth-Seeking Balls was the strongest Naruto transformation, but he didnt use it when fighting Jigen in Boruto, and Sasuke and him were defeated so if it was the strongest form there was no apparent reason not to use it.

What's the strongest Naruto transformation?

Comment: Having not watched much of Boruto I can't really answer the question, but a partial answer at least is that Naruto lost the ability to use the truth seeking balls form at the end of Shippuden.

Answer (score 3):

**Alert (if you have not read the manga series yet), this includes spoilers.**

Naruto's confirmed ultimate form (for now) is Baryon Mode, where both him and Kurama enter in a significant higher level of 'fusion'.

According to ScreenRant blog:

> Naruto's new form is officially called Baryon Mode, and according to Kurama, involves smashing Naruto's chakra and the Nine-Tails' chakra together in a manner similar to nuclear fusion, creating an entirely new energy.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the ScreenRant article you're referring to?

Comment: @F1Krazy I believe it is this: https://screenrant.com/naruto-nine-tails-baryon-mode-transformation-boruto-explained/